# Referring to frames

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to create a setting in my UWP 10 app so the user can change the app theme at runtime. I found an interesting article http://www.guruumeditation.net/en/changing-app-theme-on-the-fly-with-requestedtheme/ where this is done with a public class named **ThemeAwareFrame**:

```
public class ThemeAwareFrame : Frame
{
    private static readonly ThemeProxyClass _themeProxyClass = new ThemeProxyClass();
 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppThemeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AppTheme", typeof (ElementTheme), typeof (ThemeAwareFrame),
 new PropertyMetadata(default(ElementTheme), (d,e) => _themeProxyClass.Theme = (ElementTheme)e.NewValue));
 
 
    public ElementTheme AppTheme
    {
        get { return (ElementTheme) GetValue(AppThemeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppThemeProperty, value); }
    }
 
    public ThemeAwareFrame()
    {
        var themeBinding = new Binding { Source = _themeProxyClass, Path = new PropertyPath("Theme") };
        SetBinding(RequestedThemeProperty, themeBinding);
    }
 
    // Proxy class to be used as singleton
    sealed class ThemeProxyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ElementTheme _theme;
 
        public ElementTheme Theme
        {
            get { return _theme; }
            set
            {
                _theme = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the **App.xaml.cs** file it is then referenced to like this:

```
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {

            rootFrame = new ThemeAwareFrame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

        }

        if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Shell), e.Arguments);
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

On the different pages the app theme then can be changed using the following code:

```
(Frame as ThemeAwareFrame).AppTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
```

or

```
(Frame as ThemeAwareFrame).AppTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
```

The code works fine if it is handled with an event on the page named Shell. However, in my app Shell acts as a navigation page with a SplitView menu and loads the different pages, for example Settings, into a Frame named MyFrame. If i try to move the code to the Settings page I get a NullReferenceExeption because the page now sits in MyFrame.
Does anyone have a solution how I can get this to work? (I'm new to c# programing;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NullReferenceExeption because the page now sits in MyFrame.

This is because you defined the `MyFrame` in the `SplitView` by `<Frame x:Name="MyFrame" />` which `MyFrame`  will be a `Frame` element not a `ThemeAwareFrame` element, so when you try to get it by `Frame as ThemeAwareFrame` you got null since you don't have a `ThemeAwareFrame` object but you only have a `Frame` object.

On the `Settings` page, if you want to change the theme color of current frame `MyFrame`, you need to define `MyFrame` which is inside `SplitView` as `ThemeAwareFrame`  like follows:

```
<local:ThemeAwareFrame x:Name="MyFrame" Margin="0,5,0,0"   />
```

If you want to change the theme color of rootFrame(`Window.Current.Content`), you need to change the `DarkTheme_OnClick` code like follows:

```
private void DarkTheme_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThemeAwareFrame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as ThemeAwareFrame;
    rootFrame.AppTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
 }
```